# ideas for storing images with alt tags in a database/cms? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple CMS and have the login, edit pages etc.

Those of you who have built your own CMS, how do you store user uploaded images with an alt tag?

File name/path in the database and alt tag there too?

Then grab the id when writing out the image and create a php page that acts as an image?

eg:
`<?php include image.php?id=1; ?>`

image.php outputs:

```
get id
connect to db
echo '<img src="nameofimageandextension" alt="alttag">';
```

Or would that not be a good idea?

Comment: where else do you think one could store it?

Comment: well IMage would be stored in a server folder and link or filename to that image is saved in a database, the alt tag will also be saved in a database table. Its a very very very simple approach.

Comment: Better to avoid html in the database. Convention over configuration as reflected in #kami's answer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the problem in creating a table ( or an extension to your user table ) something like this?

```
+----+----------------+------------------+
| id | name           | alt_tag          |
+----+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | myimage.png    | My image         |
|  2 | otherimage.jpg | Some other image |
+----+----------------+------------------+
```

And access it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT name, alt_tag FROM images WHERE id = ?";
$params = array( 1 );

$path = "http://mysite.com/path/to/image/";

$stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute( $params );
$row = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

echo '<img src="{$path.$row[name]}" alt="{$row[alt_tag]}" title="{$row[alt_tag]}" />';
```

I believe this is the cleanest and easiest ( *best?* ) way to do it.

And to answer to the 2nd question:

Depends on how you want to protect your images, but normally, **no**, it's better to show the real image link. You don't want users to see all images as `myimage.php?id=1` style unless those are *captcha* or other `one time use only` images.
Using PHP as image url messes up some browser cache, so this will mean that a user has to load **your entire site** every time (s)he wisits it.

Not pleasant for the user or your server traffic.

Comment: There is no problem in doing that, and I have done that in the past. This is mainly how the image is written out in the code, do I call a PHP file to connect to the DB and write out the `<img>` tag inc alt info, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Depends on how you want to protect your images, but normally, **no**, it's better to show the real image link.

Comment: @williamsongibson NO you use one call to the database and return Object/Array of the row values, then you build your html and echo these values inside html. I suggest you read about MySQL select a little bit more before deciding building your CMS, you gonna use that pretty very much, [CHECK THIS OUT](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php)

Answer (score 3):

Storing the name and the alt text seems like the best solution.  The path can then be configured to be static, ie, `/user/upload` or something similar.

The images when required will then have to be routed through php to ensure the alt text is displayed.

```
  <img src="<?php echo $imagePath . $imageNameFromDB; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imageAltFromDB; ?>"/>
```

Comment: I've amended my initial question slightly. Is the way of writing out the php file via a php script a good idea?

Comment: What you are quoting is the same thing as my code, but in an include file.  As long as you used that as the entire image tag, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The path is what i store in the database like-- resources/myimage.png . But for it to work you have to insert it into the database mysql as--  resources . myimage.png I do this this way--->

$upload_path = 'resources/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).
   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.
   $avatar = $upload_path . $filename;    //here is the key. Asighn a var for both and the dot= your /(forward-slash)between them. Then sanitise and check it then when you insert it using the query like so-- mysql_query('update users set avatar=" '.$avatar.' " where id=  and thats it.

Comment: You could easily store the Alt Tag the same way ! Within your db add the alt field and you can pass the value as a hidden input that gets passed--> input id="a_value" name="a_value" type="text"THEN ADD value="hidden" Along with the passed file-name input tag. Not sure if that is what you need though ! If you are having this to show a gravatar where users do not upload an image,,i would suggest using a IF statement to switch them on a condition. I have the full script to do that. Either way you could easily send a default gravatar as it seems as a Alt and then have it changeable like WordPress.

Comment: Here is a sample--->http://codesneekers.blogspot.com/2012/09/member-switch-profile-image-to-avatar.html#.UKDX24fAdlM